# Query Account field IsExcludedFromRealign

Tags: soql, account, assignment-rules, territory-management

There is a field on Account called IsExcludedFromRealign which determines that if Account is excluded from Territory Assignment or not. I am having an issue where some of my accounts are not assigned to a territory even though they match the criteria. (More about this on this link: [Why Account Assignment Rules removes Account from Territory?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46470/why-account-assignment-rules-removes-account-from-territory)) However, I am unable to query this field in Workbench or Dataloader. How do I get the data of this field?

Answer (score 1):

Your query would look something like this:

```
select id, Name, IsExcludedFromRealign from account where IsExcludedFromRealign = true/false
```

I've tested it and it should work, of course choose true or false.

Also, here's a pic of my run:
[image: Dataloader]

Comment: I tried the above query in workbench but it didn't work. Where did you ran the query? And what was the API version if it was workbench or data loader?

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it returning 0? I am running this in dataloader v.30.0.0 --- Please refer to my edits in my answer above. Make sure you are not capitalizing false or true.

Comment: Tried the query on Workbench and Datalaoder with version 30. It throws the error "No such column 'IsExcludedFromRealign' on entity 'Account'." Was there some special setting or permission that was enabled on your org (like an audit field)?

Comment: When did you enable territory management? If you are not able to view it, you might want to contact support. It should be able to be queried after having territories enabled by SF.

Comment: Territories were enabled a couple of months back. I will raise a case with Salesforce on this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem with the Data Loader, Workbench, and SoqlExplorer. It doesn't seem like this is available via API. Either that or you (and I) should log a case with SFDC.